# Style custom links (outside of navbar-nav) in navbar like others Bootstrap Bootswatch

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootswatch

I have a navbar in which some of the navbar links always show, even in collapse mode. I am using Bootswatch's Paper theme: [Bootswatch Paper Theme](https://bootswatch.com/paper/).

Desktop:
[image]

Mobile/Collapsed:
[image]

The content that continues to show is done by adding 'navbar'header' to a div and pulling it right, so the default styling is not applied to the links inside that.

I have applied some styles, but there are still a few issues.

- I am not able to add anchor () tag to the links that always show (i.e. 'Show Link 1')
- If I click on the Username dropdown and click and hold one of the menu links (i.e. Profile), then the color changes:

[image]

However, it should look similar to the default dropdown (on the left):
[image]

```
<div class="navbar-header navbar-right pull-right">
    <ul class="nav pull-left">
        <li class="navbar-text navbar-link pull-left navbar-always-show">Show Link 1</li>
        <li class="navbar-text navbar-link pull-left navbar-always-show">Show Link 2</li>
        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="user-dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                User Name <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="navbar-link">
                    <a href="/users/id" title="Profile">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/logout" title="Logout">Logout </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r32eojo/)

---

Is there a way to add to/modify the variable file so the default styling can be applied regardless of which Bootswatch theme is used, and/or even default Bootstrap theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your issues correctly:

- I am not able to add anchor () tag to the links that always show
  (i.e. 'Show Link 1')

Try to add the anchor tag before the `<li>`

```
   <a href="#"><li class="navbar-text navbar-link pull-left
       navbar-always-show">Show Link 1</li></a>
```

- If I click on the Username dropdown and click    and hold one of the 
  menu links (i.e. Profile), then the color    changes:

There are two things that you can do:

You can either add an extra class to `ul` in the html and then add style to override the default css, or just override the default style for nav.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav pull-left nav-override">
```

CSS

```
.nav-override .open > a, .nav-override .open > a:hover, .nav-override .open > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff!important;
    background-color: #0c7cd5!important;
}
```

or

```
.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff!important;
    background-color: #0c7cd5!important;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r32eojo/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Adding the anchor tag breaks things when collapsed. And The background of the "User name" should behave like last image.

Comment: Changed the css in the answer to have the background as the last image. Could you tell me the expected layout for the collapse nav?

Comment: Have you tried opening the username dropdown, click and holding on one of the options? Background shows like the 3rd image, but it should be like the 4th.

Comment: Updated the answer and fiddle, was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you! Do you know of any way to generalize and add this to the theme's variable section so it can be applied to any theme from bootswatch?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I think it is best if you override it in the main.css, this way you have more control over the changes, but thats just my opinion.

Comment: Each theme would have a different styling. Should I go through and override styling for each theme as needed?